# C# WebApi deployed in docker is not exposing port to local machine

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile

Currently, I have app (.Net Core 3.1) which is listening on port 40003. Now I'm trying to put it into a container. I created dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 40003

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myProject/myProject/myProject.csproj", "myProject/myProject/"]

RUN dotnet restore "myProject/myProject/myProject.csproj" --configfile ./NuGet.Config
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myProject/myProject"
RUN dotnet build "myProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:40003
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="development"
EXPOSE 40003
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myProject.dll"]
```

As you see I exposed port 40003 and set variable ASPNETCORE_URLS.
I run it:

```
docker run -it --rm --name myTag -p 40003:40003 myTag
```

When I log into container:

```
docker exec -it myTag bash
```

and executing:

```
wget http://localhost:40003
```

I got the expected result. So I believe that my component inside the container is alive and listening
However when I am trying to go to

```
http://localhost:40003
```

from my local browser, I'm receiving ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Can you give some advice? Thank you in advance.

Edit:===================

I posted a complete docker file. (added first 3 lines to docker file which defines base).

Yes I'm sure that I posted to HTTP (not https).

http://localhost:40003 returns correct response which is a custom "selftest"
On not development env this endpoint is blocked. Something like:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult<DiagnosticsResult> ServerStatus()
```

The response: I really got no response. No 200, 404 etc. simple nothing.
Also I'm logging now that result of self tests. Above when I'm inside the docker

```
INFORMATION 2021-11-30 09:15:48,738 [Omdc.SelfHost.Base.Tests.MinimumDiskSpaceTest.Run] MinimumDiskSpaceTest starting.
INFORMATION 2021-11-30 09:15:48,741 [Omdc.SelfHost.Base.Tests.MinimumDiskSpaceTest.Run] Drive: /, Volume label: /, Total available space: 82%
```

But when I'm requesting from a local browser there are neither console logs nor HTTP responses.
So my request to not reach the endpoint (?)

Comment: It looks good to me. One thing I noticed in your Dockerfile is that you have `FROM base AS final` but you never define what the base image is. Have you posted the complete Dockerfile?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API projects use HTTPS by default and redirect HTTP requests to the HTTPS endpoint. You have to explicitly disable HTTPS. Are you sure `wget` connects to just HTTP and doesn't get redirected to HTTPS?

Comment: Use the Network tab in the browser's developer tools to see what's going on and what the actual response is. `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` is what the browser displays, not the actual response itself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It gives a warning and falls back to using http when there isn't an https endpoint defined in ASPNETCORE_URLS

Comment: Another thing: Since you've made a webapi application, it seems odd that you'd expect a response on http://localhost:40003/. I would think you'd specify an API endpoint with a controller name. I.e. for the template webapi app, the URL would be http://localhost:40003/weatherforecast.